# How to read Google Form emailAddress Value before submit?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-forms

[Google Mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76vSa.png)

I want to capture the email value before submitting the Google form

[Triggering conditions seting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQU8M.png)

Give me an GAS example,thank u
How to get google sign in value?
I hope to get google mail before submitting the google form,
Only then can I determine whether it is a blacklisted user

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it is not possible to intercept the form submit process of Google forms, before the actual submit. Consider creating a pure html/js form instead.

Comment: How to read emailAddress?

Comment: I found a solution.[FormResponse.getRespondentEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response?hl=en#getRespondentEmail())

Comment: @王大大 See doubleunary comment above. You can use `getRespondentEmail()` **AFTER** submission, but NOT **before**

Comment: @doubleunary `only collect email addresses when you have a Google Workspace domain account` Is this a new restriction? Used to be able to collect email addresses in Google forms before without domain account.

Comment: You're correct — the **Collect email addresses** option is nowadays available to personal accounts as well (that wasn't always the case.)

Comment: thank u,everyone